# I Can't get all selected checkboxes to print ! (Array)

Tags: javascript, php

I am struggling to get my QR codes to line up to print, I have a list of QR codes and wanted to check and Print SELECTED, I am almost there. but I got Stuck on Iterating throgh.. When I click Print it only prints Array[0] by default. I wanted to print ALL slected items on a popup Print window.
Here is my Code:
Hi All, 
I am struggling to get my QR codes to line up to print, I have a list of QR codes and wanted to check and Print SELECTED, I am almost there. but I got Stuck on Iterating through.. When I click Print it only prints Array[0] by default. I wanted to print ALL slected items on a popup Print window.
Here is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function PrintQR() {
    var codes = document.getElementsByClassName("QR")[0].innerHTML
    for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
      var popupWin = window.open('', 'blank');
      popupWin.document.open();
      popupWin.document.write('' + '<html>' + '<body onload="window.print()">' + '<div class="Q">' + codes + '</div>' + '</body>' + '</html>');
      popupWin.document.close();
      setTimeout(function() {
        popupWin.close();
      }, 10);
    }
  };
</script>
//MY Submit Button Here :
<div>
  <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="PrintQR()"> Print This </button></center>
</div>
Here is my FORM:
<form method="POST">
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['qrcode'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['qrcode']);
        echo "You have selected following " . $checked_count . " option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach ($_POST['qrcode'] as $selected) {
            $output = '
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="QR">
    <center><img src="userQr/' . $selected . '" /> </center>
    </div>
    ';
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
?>
</form>
```

It's only printing First Array, sometimes when I would try and it would give me an "HTML Collection" Javascript error !
Any Help will be appreciated .
Thank you all for the CLEVER Work here at Stackoverflow .
Ed-

Comment: Unless you have a canvas you are using to create the QR, you might as well just save the images and put them in your HTML, without even using PHP.

Comment: Yes Sir, I do have a system in place that generates QR codes and store them in a a MySQL table .. it's when i get them out to print that I am facing this challenge...
@giuseppedeponte Is right, there is no need to loop through, but then I am facing a one shot page versus Qr templates (Margins etc) ... any idea is welcome.
Many Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly selecting only the first element here:

```
var codes = document.getElementsByClassName("QR")[0].innerHTML
```

You should select all the elements and the loop on them. Here is an example:

```js
function PrintQR() {
  var codes = document.querySelectorAll('.QR');

  codes = [...codes].map(code => code.innerHTML);

  console.log(codes.join('\n'));
  // Uncomment the following on your real page

  /*
  var popupWin = window.open('', 'blank');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('' + '<html>' + '<body onload="window.print()">' + '<div class="Q">' + code + '</div>' + '</body>' + '</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function() {
    popupWin.close();
  }, 10);
  */
};
```

```html
<div>
  <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="PrintQR()"> Print This </button></center>
</div>
<form method="POST">
  You have selected following 3 option(s): <br />
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="QR">
    <center><img src="userQr/1" /> </center>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="QR">
    <center><img src="userQr/2" /> </center>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="QR">
    <center><img src="userQr/3" /> </center>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Update**
Since you want to print all the images in one run, you do not need to loop over them. The above snippet has been updated to show an example without the loop. 
You will probably need some CSS styles in order for the images to each print on a different page.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but now it is printing ONLy the last One, and by Printing I meant Print to printer, A popup will show and the only QR code that's displayed is the Last one in the Array... I really want them to show all in the popup Print preview window before printing and Yes I have selected Pages All. Many Thanks.! Ed-

Comment: I appreciate your Help Sir, Just so you know I am Printing QR on a Dymo Labelwriter 450 Turbo (Template 30334),Now they are showing up I managed to hide unnecessary HTML that should not pring like (Buttons and Print this) 
<style>
  @media print 
   {
    body > div 
    {
     display:none; 
    }
    body .div 
    {
     display:block; 
    }
   }
   
  </style>
Only issue now it is treating the whole thing as one Shot Print (Page), so Obviously Margins are an issue here :-( 
Any idea ?
Many Thanks in Advance .
Ed-

Comment: For page breaks you can take a look here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after. For margins, I think you should rather play with your printer settings configuration to find the right layout for your use case.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to the CSS.. I found this and it worked well for me...
<style type="text/css" media="print">
      div.page
      {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
    </style>
On DymoLabelWriter 450 Turbo.
Template 30334 for QR codes
Layout Landscape
Margins: minimum
Scale: Custom: 110 (For big enough QR image).
Quality 300x600 for better resultion on Laser Printer.

Many Thanks to – giuseppedeponte.
Appreciate it so much.
Ed-

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sir,  but now it is printing ONLy the last One, and by Printing I meant Print to printer, A popup will show and the only QR code that's displayed is the Last one in the Array...
I really want them to show all in the popup Print preview window before printing and Yes I have selected Pages All.
Many Thanks.!
Ed-